How can I calculate the time difference between two timestamps in PostgreSQL when they span different days?
I'm working with BigQuery to analyze bike trip data and each trip has a start_time and end_time in timestamp format. I want to calculate the time difference between these two timestamps, but some trips start before midnight and end the next day. For example, if a trip starts at 11:00pm and ends at 6:00 am the next day, I need to calculate the duration as 7 hours. Currently, I'm using the following query:
SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time, start_time, HOUR) AS duration
FROM fast-audio-430317-q9.citibike_trips;

That works fine for the trips that start and end on the same day, but for trips crossing at midnight, the results is negative. How can I handle the trips that span multiple days to get the right duration in hours?

Did you try the obvious DATETIME_DIFF?

That's a good question. From now on when working with TIMESTAMP, I could used DATETIME_DIFF instead in terms of subtracting two timestamps values.

Try (epoch(end_date) - epoch(start_date))/3600

You can just subtract timestamps. So end_time - start_time. This will give the duration as an interval. See [documentation}9https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

@Belayer yes, but if you get extract hours from an interval it gives you the hours of the interval, not the interval in hours
